# Populate a <select> list from a server side collection upon the user selecting a value in another list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

If a user selects a value from an HTML drop down list *A*, I want to make an ajax call to the server to populate the values in HTML drop down list *B* based on the user's selection.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF 4. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for the change event of first drop down and then load the content of second drop down in `JSON` format and inject that to the second drop down

```
<select id="country">
  <option value='1'>USA</option>
  <option value='2'>Canada</option>
</select>
<select id="States"></select>
```

and the script

```
$(function(){
  $("#country").change(function(){
    var _this=$(this);
    var items="";
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetStates","Country")/"+_this.val(),function(data){
           if(data.Status==="Success")
           {
              $.each(data.Items,function(index, item){
                 items=+"<option value='"+item.ID+'">"+item.Name+"</option>";
              });                 
           }
           $("#states").html(items);
    });
  });       
});
```

Assuming your `GetStates` action method returns `JSON` data with ID and Name as below.

```
public ActionResult GetStates(int id)
{
  List<State> stateList=yourRepositary.GetStatesForCountry(id);
  return Json(new { Status="Success", Items=stateList},
                                           JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming `GetStatesForCountry` method returns a list of State object with `ID` and `Name` as properties.

Comment: Thanks for the functions. Couple of corrections in the loop I believe...
       $.each(data.Items, function (index, item) {
 items += "<option value='"+item.ID+"'>"+item.Name+"</option>";
});

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is your best friend. First bind the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to your dropdownlist A and then make the ajax call to the server. Finally take the response and set it to your dropdownlist B

```
$('#ddlA').change(function() {
    $('#ddlB').load('server/pageThatReturnsHtml')
});
```

This assumes that 'server/pageThatReturnsHtml' returns html such as:

```
<option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
```

But you could also return a json object and iterate over the result to add items to your ddl B